# Encoding problem in C# decrypting in bouncycastle from openssl

Tags: c#, encryption, openssl, bouncycastle, php-openssl

I'm trying to decrypt in c#, using bouncycastle, the result of the following php code:

```php
<?php
    $plaintext = 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog';
    $cipher = "AES-128-CTR";
    $key = "F5UgsDQddWGdgjddJtNgg6xE3V9uwaCR";
    if (in_array($cipher, openssl_get_cipher_methods()))
    {
        $ivlen = openssl_cipher_iv_length($cipher);
        $iv = '2782614358578542';
        $ciphertext = openssl_encrypt($plaintext, $cipher, $key, $options=0, $iv, $tag);
        echo $ciphertext."\n";
    }
?>
```

My c# code is as follows:

```cs
public string Decrypt(string toDecrypt, string keyStr, string ivStr)
{
    byte[] inputBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(toDecrypt);
    byte[] keyBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(keyStr);
    byte[] iv = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(ivStr);
    IBufferedCipher cipher = CipherUtilities.GetCipher("AES/CTR/PKCS7PADDING");
    cipher.Init(false, new ParametersWithIV(ParameterUtilities.CreateKeyParameter("AES", keyBytes), iv));
    byte[] decryptedBytes = cipher.DoFinal(inputBytes);
    return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decryptedBytes);
}
```

The php code returns

```
7/q61uOzeC4iycFIMrjvh01zvjOuCtnX8eWob8MAA5kIfMOIx915ctBIyw==
```

But when I make in C# the following call

```cs
Decrypt("7/q61uOzeC4iycFIMrjvh01zvjOuCtnX8eWob8MAA5kIfMOIx915ctBIyw==", "F5UgsDQddWGdgjddJtNgg6xE3V9uwaCR", "2782614358578542");
```

I get the following gibberish:

```
���yF�l����c:�-��7K�(�,�X�.[�W"�ܜ��J�
```

Which makes me think that I'm missing or doing something wrong with the encoding but I can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AES-128 uses a 16 bytes key. In the PHP code, however, a 32 bytes key is used, which PHP *implicitly* truncates by considering only the first 16 bytes.

So the fix is to shorten the key in the C# code accordingly, i.e. use  `F5UgsDQddWGdgjdd`.
Alternatively, change the AES variant in the PHP code to AES-256 (`aes-256-ctr`), which results in the ciphertext `Tw05j9QDfaBK7zbyt9jine8xWqnzNB2Pim7rtv7gDba2TsE7ejvvjP5YKA==`.

Additionally, in the C# code, apply `AES/CTR/NoPadding`, since CTR is a stream cipher mode that does not require padding, which is why padding is *implicitly* disabled in the PHP code.

---

Note that for security reasons, key/IV pairs must not be reused, especially for CTR. Therefore, for a fixed key, a static IV must not be applied, but a random one (which is passed to the decrypting side together with the ciphertext, usually concatenated).

Comment: When I do in c# var random = new SecureRandom(); var iv = random.GenerateSeed(16); decryption doesn't work and I get gibberish but when I do var iv = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("2782614358578542"); it works. Do you have any ideas why that is?

Comment: @yqit - You must use the same IV for decryption as for encryption. As already described in the last section of my answer, the (random) IV must therefore be passed together with the ciphertext to the decrypting side, typically concatenated: IV|ciphertext (note that the IV is not secret). On the decrypting side, both parts are separated based on the known length of the IV.